# Which regular expression to use to convert this string to an array?

Tags: php, regex, geojson

From a geospatial column in mysql I'm getting the following string-value which I want to convert into an array. Ultimate goal is to convert it to geoJSON.

```
POLYGON((4.885838 52.388063,4.891061 52.388381,4.890973 52.382909))
```

This string has 3 coordinate pairs with the x and y coordinate separated by a space and the pairs separated with a comma. The exact number is not known and variable. Also the `POLYGON` can differ to three different settings.

With my little knowledge of reg. expressions I came up with this:

```
$pat = '/^(POLYGON|LINESTRING|POINT)(\(\() (.....) (\)\))$/';
preg_match($pat, $str, $matches);
```

With the part of the coordinates with the double brackets as an uncertain part.

Could anyone help me with this?

**edit** Ultimately the resulting array should look like this:

```
$array['type'] = POLYGON | LINESTRING ....
$array['coordinates'] = array of all the coordinates.
```

Comment: How should the array look like?

Comment: Added an example result array. Thank you for looking into it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's easier and more maintainable to just use [explode](http://php.net/explode) and [array_map](http://php.net/array_map) on the coordinate string:

```
$coordString = $matches[3];
$coordinates = array_map(function($e) { return explode(' ', $e); },
                         explode(',', $coordString));
```

Answer (score 2):

You're best off tackling this in stages. Only the first stage needs to use regex:

1. Find the entire string of coordinates as one glob, for example:

   `"4.885838 52.388063,4.891061 52.388381,4.890973 52.382909"`
2. Split that string up into coordinate pairs separated by comma. In Python, we would use `str.split(',')`. I believe your PHP equivalent is called `explode()`.

   `[ "4.885838 52.388063" , "4.891061 52.388381" , "4.890973 52.382909" ]`
3. Split each coordinate pair into two numbers separated by space: `str.split(' ')`.

   `[ ["4.885838","52.388063"] , ["4.891061","52.388381"] , ["4.890973","52.382909"] ]`
4. Convert to floats. In python we use `float()`: your local equivalent might be called `str2float()` or similar.

   `[ [4.885838,52.388063] , [4.891061,52.388381] , [4.890973,52.382909] ]`

To find the string of numbers for step 1, try the regex

```
([-]?\d+.\d+ [-]?\d+.\d+)((,[-]?\d+.\d+ [-]?\d+.\d+)+)?
```

which finds at least one pair of coordinates in `x y` format, with coordinate pairs separated by commas. You can see the regular expression in action on [regexr](http://regexr.com?30uja).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I used the method you described but the function of emil Vikström.

Answer (score 0):

I have stumbled into the same problem, however in my case I found patterns such as `POLYGON ((-1.23 2.34, 3.45 4.56), (3.21 4.32, 5.43 6.54))` and the above regular expression did not work for me to perform step 1. After some head scratching I came with the following pattern: `/(((([-]?\d+\.\d+) ([-]?\d+\.\d+))[, ]?)+[, ]?)+/`. You would then iterate over the matches splitting on the commas and finally split on the spaces. I am not a regex guru, so maybe someone has a better solution.