# python regular expression for extracting coordinates

Tags: regex

Can someone help me with a regex to extract the 3-D coordinates within the MULTIPOLYGON  in this list:

```
[(1,
  'public Library',
  'SRID=4326;MULTIPOLYGON(((352877.02163887 1233618.83923531 5,352872.32998848 1233609.44478035 5,352867.693426132 1233612.15611458 5,352861.67354393 1233602.76770592 5,352841.814386368 1233616.9818058 5,352848.495328903 1233625.69463921 5,352861.076768875 1233617.56668663 5,352866.429475784 1233626.28557014 5,352877.02163887 1233618.83923531 5)))')]
```

Comment: What do you want to get as output?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which regular expression to use to convert this string to an array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10579889/which-regular-expression-to-use-to-convert-this-string-to-an-array)

Answer (score 2):

I think this regex may find what you're looking for in your string:  '([\d.]+?)\s([\d.]+?)\s([\d.]+?)'

I tested it with python and it returns a list of lists of coordinates:

```
import re
foo = "SRID=4326;MULTIPOLYGON(((352877.02163887 1233618.83923531 5,352872.32998848 1233609.44478035 5,352867.693426132 1233612.15611458 5,352861.67354393 1233602.76770592 5,352841.814386368 1233616.9818058 5,352848.495328903 1233625.69463921 5,352861.076768875 1233617.56668663 5,352866.429475784 1233626.28557014 5,352877.02163887 1233618.83923531 5)))"
print re.findall('([\d.]+?)\s([\d.]+?)\s([\d.]+?)', foo)
```

It prints:

```
[('352877.02163887', '1233618.83923531', '5'), ('352872.32998848', '1233609.44478035', '5'), ('352867.693426132', '1233612.15611458', '5'), ('352861.67354393', '1233602.76770592', '5'), ('352841.814386368', '1233616.9818058', '5'), ('352848.495328903', '1233625.69463921', '5'), ('352861.076768875', '1233617.56668663', '5'), ('352866.429475784', '1233626.28557014', '5'), ('352877.02163887', '123361 8.83923531', '5')]
```